# Kali Linux 2022.1 Fresh installation DNS Problems resolv.conf missing

Tags: kali-linux, resolv.conf

I am dealing with DNS Problems on my freshly installed Kali Linux Machine.

I can connected to my Home Network, wired and wireless. I can also Ping my default Gateway and Google DNS Server 8.8.8.8 .

But google.com doesnt work in a webbrowser.

What i tried so far is changing `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

```
prepend domain-name-server 8.8.8.8
```

What I also tried edditng `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

To my suprise resolv.conf didn't exist and I couldn't create it. And yes I had root rights:

> Mousepad Error
>
> Failed to save the document. Error opening file "/etc/resolv.conf" Too
> many levels of symbolic links.

Yet the file seems to exist but the run/systemd/resolve/ folder doesnt:

```
    ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 39 Apr 22 10:42 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
    ls -l /run/systemd/resolve/
    ls: cannot access 'run/systemd/resolve/' No such file or directory
```

Then I tried to install the `resolvconf` package

```
apt install resolvconf
Package resolveconf is not available
```

Do you have any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Your `/etc/resolv.conf` is not missing, but there's a problem with the way it's set up which is why you can't write to it. (But even if you did it would probably get overwritten shortly afterwards.) Please add `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf` to your question

Comment: `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 39 Apr 22 10:42 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

Comment: Thank you. Please do not use the comments to add information. I've copied your reply into the question so that it can easily be seen by everyone.

Comment: Thx for your help did so but strangefully there is noch /run/systemd/resolve checked the spelling twice

Comment: So it helped me . THX It know resolving DNS. Maybe you can  tell me where i can change my DNS settings. /etc/resolv.conf telling me not to change itself

Comment: Please avoid scope-creep. You've got an answer to the question you actually asked, so tell the system that the suggested answer did indeed help you. Then ask a new question, possibly referencing this one for context.

Comment: @roaima In order for the OP to accept an answer, it actually has to be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @doneal24 there's an "does this other question answer your problem" duplicate flag raised. That's what the OP can accept